# java - finding out which type of exception to throw

Tags: java

I am confronting with the following issue for some time.

Let's say you have some code and at some point you need to throw an exception. Let's suppose we want to throw a runtime exception.

Java comes with plenty of exceptions and, in some cases, you may find one suitable for your case.

The problem is how can I figure out which of the exceptions is most suitable for my case?

My question is only about the existent Java implementations of `RuntimeException` and not custom exception which are extending this class.

Let's take an example. I have the following switch statement:

```
switch(something){
  case A: ... break;
  case B: ... break;
  default: throw new AJavaRuntimeException("No such case defined");
}
```

What should I use instead of `AJavaRuntimeException` and comes with Java? How to find the proper exception through Java?

The easiest solution would be to extend `RuntimeException` and create `NoSuchSwitchCaseDefinedException`. Or even throw a `RuntimeException`. But... Maybe Java already has something for this.

Comment: Well where did `something` come from, and what does the failure of it to be a handled case *mean*? Maybe `IllegalArgumentException` is appropriate, for example...

Comment: I use Eclipse. What I do, in this situation is:
I write only the try block, and, no catch block.
Then Eclipse throws some error.
Eclipse itself suggests which exception I should use. I just use them.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer You don't put any consideration into it at all?

Comment: @khelwood , This is just a shortcut if you don't know the kind of exception it is throwing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsing the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) for **Direct known subclasses** of `RuntimeException` will probably get you your best fit out of the "catalog".

In this case, you could either throw:

- [IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html), signalling an illegal state in your program or
- [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), signalling a bad argument
- Etc...

If you can't find your exact match, you shouldn't hesitate to extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException` depending on your requirements (checked vs not checked).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to throw an exception independently, better throw a custom user defined exception and it has to be checked one.
Never throw runtime exceptions on your own.
Create business exceptions and throw them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many philosophies to follow here. The philosophy I follow is that *unchecked exceptions* (i.e. everything inheriting from *RuntimeException* or *Error*) are solely used to report *programming errors* (e.g. though an error dialog or a log message). Programming errors should only be handled in a generic way (e.g. by aborting an operation, skipping an optional processing step, etc.). This means that the actual type used for the exception does not matter in a *technical* sense.

What does matters is that the exception, its name, its message, its accompanying JavaDoc comment make it as simple as possible to identify what triggered the bug, what a possible workaround might be and how to fix the bug in the end.

If you are writing a library that might fail because of incorrect usage, having domain-specific unchecked exceptions might make working with the library more pleasant because you have the opportunity to provide a lot of context and documentation to an error that might otherwise be obscure.

If you are writing an end-user application or service, you or your time are probably one of the only people ever seeing those exception so that extra work might not be worth it and just throwing `RuntimeException` with a short description of the problem as its message might be enough.